# C# - Globally intercept and modify DNS resolution responses

Tags: c#, .net, windows, dns, intercept

There's a similar question ( [Can I temporarily override DNS resolution within a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992700/can-i-temporarily-override-dns-resolution-within-a-net-application) ) but I just can't figure it out with the meager response there.

---

### Background info

I have a server set up in my home network, an old computer. Our router has the right ports forwarded, the server runs server software for things like http, svn, games, etc. I've got a domain name registered that always points to our external IP address. For all intents and purposes, I've got a typical webserver set up. My friends can game on my server by connecting via the domain name, I can push and pull svn projects, etc.

The only problem is that I also need to use my server when I'm connected to my home network (the same network as the server). Using the domain name results in Windows resolving it to our own IP address, and my router is too retarded to realize it just needs to forward it back into our network to the server as per the usual. I've done some looking around, configuring, telnetting and DNS overriding, but I have it on good authority that our ISP apparently crippled the DNS override feature of their routers to prevent this exact scenario. Apparently they don't like internal loopbacks.

I now basically have to keep 2 configs for each of my server's services: one config that specifies the domain name for when I'm abroad, and a second that specifies the server's internal IP for when I'm at home. It's frustrating because it just isn't always possible.

---

I want to instantiate a global DNS resolution request/response listener that will do the following: if the requested domain name matches a given string, override the IP in the response with one of my choice.

I've looked things up like easyhook, dllimport, msdn pages, etc, but I still can't figure out where to actually start, which classes I need to get access to, and so on. I basically have no pre-existing code for this particular problem.

I have Visual Studio, years of relatively simple programming experience and a good understanding of unfamiliar code and everything else, just no idea how to start or what to look for.

Many thanks for anything that can get me going.

Comment: If you are ok to use existing tools - Fiddler probably would do that (for your client machine to rewrite server's IP).

Comment: Don't try to write application layer DNS Trickery, it's just not the right layer to do it and you'll always be fighting the built in TCP Stack support for it.

Comment: You can use `hosts` file in `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` folder to override DNS lookup

Comment: Slava: nope, that makes it only work when I'm home and not abroad. I'm not interested in updating the hosts file everytime I change locations.

Comment: John: not sure what you mean? TCP packets have a header to replace separate DNS requests or something?

Comment: Why not just have a script to modify the Windows HOSTS file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) ?

Comment: That would require at least a reboot since my network driver seems to read the file at boot (adding insanely many lines increases boot time) and caches it for the rest of the power-on time. I do use Hostsman to have ad-blocking via the hosts file and it seems to be able to force a re-read though. I just tested it by manually editing the hosts file and testing it in my browser, it didn't apply.

Comment: Actually, editing the hosts file *and forcing a DNS cache flush* does make it apply! Now to find a way to do that, there's gotta be a service interface for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with (as a few have suggested) the hosts file after all.

I first used ManagedWifi to set a network connection monitor. It detects changes to my connection status and reports the network name.

Then I wrote a console app that stays open (using Hidden Start allows me to hide the window) and safely modifies the hosts file, then flushes the DNS cache. This seems to work in pretty much realtime. :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of pointers, DNS is as you mentioned some server somewhere that knows how to resolve a Domain name to an IP ADDRESS.  There are two types of responses 1) Definitive for the domain and 2) Not Definitive for the Domain.  Obviously any Definitive response will win.

DNS does not run at TCP/IP layer it runs one layer below using UDP (port 53).  As a result DNS is tied into the TCP/IP stack whereby the stack first looks locally  to a local host table and sees is the name is there, if it cannot find it the stack will send out the DNS request prior to the session start or SYN packet flying.  In order for this to happen, the DNS servers must resolve the address.

I do not fully understand your issue because most Windows servers only have 1 IP Address and one associated Domain name.  Unless of course they are using DHCP which just means the server uses multiple address on boot up and DNS server receive updates to what those new address are.

Public vs. Private IP addresses are the responsibility of a router.  The router is configured to do NAT (Network Address Translation).  This allows a private server to have unroutable addresses like 10.10.1.100 etc. But the router will answer ARPs for the public address making the public network think the router is the public address.  So one of your solutions could be to convert your server to a private address and use a "real" router that can perform NAT.  Port forwarding is not really routing rather it's a way to "trick" packets destined for one port number to be forwarded to another port dedicated for that application.

My suggestion is to either follow the suggestions above or add the Domain names you want to the local Host table on the server.  This will get you what you want.  A better solution is to configure your own server to be a DNS server definitive for your domain, that way you get to control everything.

Comment: This kinda goes towards total overkill... I think you didn't entirely get the root of the problem either. I call the machine downstairs a router but hell if I know what it actually is. It's something our ISP installed to receive TV, internet, etc and transmit it over wifi, ethernet, tv cable etc all around the house. The server I'm talking about is just a pc I set up here. It has an internal IP (192.168.1.9), only accessible from within our home network, and the machine downstairs holds our external IP (which is dynamic). Continue...

Comment: Continued: The domain name I registered resolves to our external IP and the server runs a script to update the domain's DNS entry with our current external IP. When someone connects via my domainname, the box downstairs receives the packets and forwards them to my "server" if that port is forwarded in the config. Everything in the last 2 paragraphs went over my head or is not applicable because I can't just install some new hardware here.

Comment: The only thing that needs to happen is for my laptop to substitute my domain name with my server's internal IP whenever I'm connected to my home network (which I have code for in C#). That way I can use my domain name wherever I am. If I use it at home right now, my router basically has to forward packets to itself and then can't figure out that their destination is right here in our home network.

Comment: I think I see what you want, you want the private address when you are in the home and the public address elsewhere.  But here's the deal when you connect locally you should be in the same network as the PC (private address wise).  If things are not working then it because an external DNS server is giving back the public address (which should work, but your reported it doesn't).  You have two choices 1) Set up DNS on your local laptop to serve the address you want or 2) Set up a Host table on your laptop.